# how a work certificate should be?

Tags: resume, work-experience, job-description, certification, websites

I was working as a Website administrator for about 6 years. Like, regular updates of the content, structural changes and improvements to the website etc.

As I had to leave, I asked my former employer for a certificate about my work, in case I would like to use it in another similar job offer. He agreed and asked me how I would like it to be.
So, is there any kind of sample or recommended guidelines for this?

Comment: What country are you in?  I think this may be specific to your region - in the US, you have references, but a hiring manager would want to speak to them, so you just need to provide a phone number.

Comment: we are both in europe but different countries

Comment: Of course, you would only provide a phone number of a reference IF they agreed to being called up.

Comment: What country in Europe? I am from Denmark and we do not use certificates from work. Could it be a written reference you are looking for?

Comment: Germany and Greece..what do you mean written reference?

Comment: @ihavenoname a written reference is when an employer writes you an employment reference, which you can then show to other potential employers. The reference should include such information as: what your job title is; when you started; the job description; and anything else they may want to write, as long as it is positive.

Comment: In my experience a company will give less weight to a public letter of recommendation that you show them than a reference directly from a referee to them (or a phone call to the referee), because a document you can open and read is less private so they can be less honest, and you can possibly even fake or tamper with it. (In contrast, if you give them a phone number for a referee they can validate that.) If you just want something saying dates and roles, that's less controversial, but still possible to fake.

Comment: Before you have this person create this certificate for you, make sure this is the standard practice in your country. In the US, if I received such a certificate with a resume, I'd throw both those papers in the trash (figuratively speaking). A phone number and a name I could call, yes. I would love that. Even if I did not speak the language of the country, I could have one of my colleagues make the call for me. But of course, don't hand this info to every company you apply to, only supply your references to an employer once they made you an offer and are asking you for your references.

Comment: And then, be sure to call/email your reference to warn them that an employer is probably going to call them. And if you need to jog their memory, you may want to email them a list of the duties you performed in case they get asked for details.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently Germany has a very weird, intricate system in which the evaluation is communicated through cryptic phrases to avoid becoming liable.  You could use generators like this: https://www.arbeitszeugnisgenerator.de/

OR just ask them to write a written reference in English and I think people will understand the context.

Answer (score 0):

This is the format used in my country (India) that can be easily customised:

> **[Date]**
>
> [**ihavenoname**] (aged xx), worked with us as a [**designation**] from [**start** period (month year)] to [**end** period (month year)]. His / her responsibility as [designation] included:
>
> 1. regular updates of the content,
> 2. structural changes
> 3. ...
> 4. improvements to the website
> 5. etc. etc. (you can exaggerate a bit if your boss is willing to accommodate it. :)
>
> He / she is qualified and skilled for his / her job, and performed all tasks assigned to him / her professionally and satisfactorily. During the period he/she worked with us, his / her professional and ethical conduct was good / excellent / exemplary. As a [designation], I am sure he / she can meet the professional expectations the industry demands and have no hesitancy in recommending him / her for similar (or better) roles in [your country] or abroad.
>
> [Signature of your boss or CEO]
>
> Name: [Name of signee]
>
> Designation: [Designation of the signee]

(Note that this is usually printed on the company's or CEO's official letter head. Sometimes an official seal is also affixed near the signature to add more legitimacy to the certificate. You can customise the language to suit your culture and your country's legal requirements.)